# PHP Infinite random number generator without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi guys im trying to create infinite random number one at a time without refreshing the whole page. For example

5 > after one sec replace 5 by other random number like 10 > after 1 sec replace 10 by random number like 8 and so on....

I sort of manage to make it work but the number doesn't refresh. It just stop after 1 click and I have to re-click it to give me another random value
This is my code

Homepage.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
<script>
var HTTP = loadXMLDoc();
var submitEvent = document.getElementById("submit-button").onclick = function(){
hello2(HTTP);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="randomNum">0</div>
<?php
    echo "<form action='randomnumber.php' method='post' style='display: inline-block'>
    <input id='submit-button' type = 'button' value='login' id='submit' />";
    echo "</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Ajax.js

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}

  var HTTP = loadXMLDoc();

  function hello2(){

    var url = "randomnumber.php";


    HTTP.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (HTTP.readyState==4 && HTTP.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("randomNum").innerHTML=HTTP.responseText;
        }
    };

    HTTP.open("POST", url ,true);
    HTTP.send();
}
```

randomnumber.php << i think this is where the problem is but i'm not too sure

```
<?php
$i = 1;

while ($i < 2) {
  $i += rand(1,5);
  echo $i;
}
?>
```

I think my randomnumber.php is not creating a loop but the only problem is i suck at loops so i'm having issue with this any help will be great :)

Comment: You need to use `setInterval` to run a Javascript function periodically.

Comment: Why are you adding a random number to your loop counter?

Comment: so i can create infinite random number. i think that's what i'm trying to do like i said loop is my weak point

Comment: I'd say the loop is going to run once with $i  = 1. Then $i gets incremented by a value between 1 and 5, so $i become something between 2 and 6 and bumps you out of the while loop on the second try.

Comment: hmm time research while loop

Comment: Is there a reason is needs to be randomized in PHP? JavaScript can be used to create the random numbers AND to exchange the content - no page refresh, fewer calls to the server, less work for PHP.

Comment: because i'm going to save that random number generated to my database so i thought i would be easy that way.

Comment: kind of want to know the basis for the project now. I'm trying to think of a use for storing a arbitrary number of random numbers instead of generating them on the fly.

Comment: atm all i want do is create random number one at a time and then display it using ajax and then i will create sqlite database and find a way to store it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your remote php code is doing right now is creating a random number between 2 and 6. I'm not sure why it's in a loop. Since `i` initializes at 1, and you're adding at least 1 to it, after the first iteration it will ALWAYS be 2 or more, thus preventing a second loop. You could do that with

```
<?php echo rand(2,6); ?>
```

You're also only making a single ajax call to the remote php file. So your page is loading, making a single ajax call, then it's done.

Try adding

```
setTimeout(hello2,1000);
```

as the last line of your `hello2()` function in the JavaScript. That will cause the function to repeat itself every second (making another call to the PHP file).

I'm not sure that will be good for writing to the database though. If the php file is going to write a new entry to the database every second, you're going to give your db admin a headache. It might be more ideal to store several of them in an array (maybe 100?) and then make a call to a different PHP file to write those numbers to the database.

In that scenario, you can skip the first call altogether (making your server work less. Have JavaScript create the integer with

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+2
```

`Math.random()` creates a random float between 0 and 1. Multiplying it by 5 makes it a random float between 0 and 5. Math.floor() rounds the value down to an integer (between 0 and 4) so add 2 to the result to make it between 2 and 6.

This puts all the work on the client browser, and you won't have the problem of slow connections. The JavaScript can store the result as an Array, making periodic calls to a PHP file to store the results in the database, then resetting the array. So, less server calls, less db writes, better performance.

Comment: thanks The E for explaining this in great detail <3. Normally people just write codes for a solution and don't explain it in detail.